# Anticommutativity of an anticommutator of supercharges

Tags: supersymmetry, fermions, lie-algebra, grassmann-numbers, anticommutator

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02095) paper, equation 38 gives the ${\cal N}=2$ Super-Poincare (extended with the central extension $\mathcal{Z}$). The anticommutation relation of the two different supercharges is given as:

$$\{Q^i,Q^j\}=-\gamma^AC^{-1}P_A\delta^{ij}+C^{-1}\mathcal{Z}\epsilon^{ij}\tag{38}.$$

This means that $$\{Q^1,Q^2\}=-\{Q^2,Q^1\}$$ which feels totally wrong since anticommutators should be symmetric, $$\{Q^1,Q^2\}=Q^1Q^2+Q^2Q^1=\{Q^2,Q^1\}.$$

Can someone please explain this apparent contradiction to me?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that $Q$ operators also carry a spinor index. The symmetry of the anticommutator works if you exchange both supercharge number and the spinor indices simultaneously. While the central charge term is antisymmetric in the supercharge number indices if it is antisymmetric in the spinor indices then it is symmetric under the simultaneous exchange of both indices.

Indeed in the paper you cite they choose the representation (they work in 3d space) $C=C^{-1}=-\sigma_2$. This matrix is antisymmetric so everything is fine.